# Expand Bootstrap datatable row and display subtable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, thymeleaf, bootstrap-4

I want to expand my bootstrap datatable after click on icon. I can make it expandable and display another table there, but my button expands every row in table in the same time. I don't know how to send exactly this td which I clicked to my function.

This is how it looks:

Before expand: [example](http://prntscr.com/hb6gby)

After click any of the '+' buttons it expands every row: [example](http://prntscr.com/hb6iy8)

Functions which expands and formats data for subtable:

```
function expandRow(list, td) {
    var tbl = $('#common_table').DataTable();
    var tr = $('.details-control').closest('tr');
    var row = tbl.row(tr);

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
        // Open this row
        row.child(format(list)).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
}

function format(operations) {
    var table = "<table id='common_table' class='table table-bordered'>";   
    table+="<thead><tr class='table_nav tableHeads'><th class='tableHead'>OPERACJE</th><tr></thead>";
        // for(i=0; i<operations.length; i++){
             table +="<tbody><tr class='row_style'><td>sadasdasddsa</td></tr></tbody>";
             //   }

     table+="</table>";
    return table;
}
```

And the way how I call this function:

```
<table>...
<tbody>
    <tr class="row_style" th:each="qcOrder : ${qcOrdersList}">
        <td class="details-control" th:onclick="'javascript:expandRow(\''+ ${qcOperationsList} +'\', \'' + this + '\');'"></td>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<tr> <td id="XXXX" colspan=10 style='display:none'>
         <!-- SUB TABLE HERE --> 
     </td>
</tr>
```

and on JS call do simple:

findElementById("XXXX")  and change style for element from 'none' to ""

Comment: Hmm I am using th:each, this generates many td and that way every td would have the same id="XXXX", so I guess function findElementById wouldn't work